# How to use Jupyter Notebook with iCloud storage to read a data set?

Tags: icloud, storage

I am trying to work with a very large dataset in my Mac. The storage space on my Mac was not enough, so I bought 50 GB of iCloud storage. But I don't know how to use it. I still cannot download data on my Mac.

I am a data scientist and I am working in [Jupyter](https://jupyter.org/) notebook. I need to save my data in iCloud and then load it from there.

Comment: What do you mean with "my storage was not enough"? Which storage exactly, the local one on your drive or the one in iCloud? In the second case why do you need to store your Jupyter notebooks in iCloud at all?

Answer (score 2):

If you haven't already, first [setup iCloud Drive on your macOS](https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT204025).

Once *iCloud Drive* is enabled on your macOS, you can access it using the `Finder`. You can now copy files to *iCloud drive* as you usually do with any other folder or drive.

The *iCloud drive* path on macOS is:

```
~/Library/Mobile\ Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/
```

So if you create a folder called *dataset* in *iCloud drive*, it's path will be

```
~/Library/Mobile\ Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/dataset
```

You need to use this as the startup folder for your Jupyter notebook as described here - [Access iCloud Drive in Jupyter Notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46444903).

Answer (score -1):

On file level iCloud basically is a syncing solution so you can't use it to extend your local storage into the cloud. You can let macOS manage your local storage by offloading everything on the Desktop and in Documents into iCloud and only download the specific things you need (see https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT206985 for details).

If you need additional local storage and can't offload stuff into iCloud it's better to buy an additional local disk.